# How to cluster images from a large dataset into groups

Tags: dataset, grouping, cluster-analysis

I want cluster an image dataset into several groups using K-means, N-cut or other algorithm, but I don't know how to process those images in the dataset first. These groups should have their own special features. Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you go ahead and try a number of features.

Which feature works best for your is ***very* much dependent on your use case**.

If you are hoping to group photos by mood, group faces by users or group CAD drawings by the type of gear on it require completely different feature extraction approaches. So you will have to kiss a few frogs to find your prince.

Answer (score 0):

You use the mosaic dataset.
A mosaic dataset allows you to store, manage, view, and query small to vast collections of raster and image data. It is a data model within the geodatabase used to manage a collection of raster datasets (images) stored as a catalog and viewed as a mosaicked image. Mosaic datasets have advanced raster querying capabilities and processing functions and can also be used as a source for serving image services. find more [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=create%20image%20data%20set&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/009t/009t00000037000000.htm&ei=-eoSUv-vKcLItQbI04DoDg&usg=AFQjCNFqdDjGyhqsWdQSPbo5EqvovZwwcA)

And also I refere you to this paper-article:
title: CREATING AN IMAGE DATASET TO MEET YOUR CLASSIFICATION NEEDS:A PROOF-OF-CONCEPT STUDY
By:
James D. Hurd, Research Associate
Daniel L. Civco, Director and Professor